# Regex for preg_match_all prices

Tags: regex, preg-match-all

I need to set Regdex for these expressions:

```
number€
number €
€number
€ number
```

Need to Output: number €

```
number$
number $
$number
$ number
```

Need to Output: number $

Do i have to write one regex for each one? Which is the easy way?

Example for number€:

```
preg_match_all("/((?:[0-9]*[.,])?[0-9]+)\p{Sc}/u", $post->post_title, $percentage, PREG_SET_ORDER);          
        if(isset($percentage[0][0]) && $percentage[0][0] != "" ){    
        $text = $percentage[0][1]." &euro;";
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to replace all `$` and `€` with `&euro;`? Or dollars with dollars and euros with euros? Are there any other currencies to consider?

Comment: No, only dollars and euros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may use one regex with a `preg_replace_callback`:

```
/(?J)(?<num>[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+)\s*(?<cur>\p{Sc})|(?<cur>\p{Sc})\s*(?<num>[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+)/u
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jjM4XW/1) and a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/F16P0F):

```
$re = '/(?J)(?<num>[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+)\s*(?<cur>\p{Sc})|(?<cur>\p{Sc})\s*(?<num>[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+)/u';
$str = '12€';
echo preg_replace_callback($re, function($m) {
    return $m["num"] . " " . $m["cur"];
}, $str);
```

Or, to *extract* the values with the `number currency` order, use the same regex and the following code:

```
$res = array();
preg_replace_callback($re, function($m) use (&$res) {
    array_push($res, $m["num"] . " " . $m["cur"]);
    return $m[0];
}, $str);
print_r($res);
```

See [another PHP demo](https://ideone.com/zq4D5c).

**Pattern details**:

- `(?J)` - PCRE_INFO_JCHANGED modifier so that the identically matched groups could be used multiple times in the pattern
- `(?<num>[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+)` - Group "num" capturing a float/integer
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?<cur>\p{Sc})` - Group "cur" capturing the currency symbol
- `|` - or  (then goes the same as above in different order)
- `(?<cur>\p{Sc})\s*(?<num>[0-9]* [.,]?[0-9]+)` - currency symbol ("cur" group), 0+ whitespaces, a float/integer (in "num" group).

Comment: Thx.But i dont need to replace the currency, i edited the question. Only need to output in the same currency but in order "number" "currency"

Comment: Great, then the solution will be a bit simpler.

Comment: I have very low php knowing, how could i integrate this instead the expression: preg_match_all("/((?:[0-9]*[.,])?[0-9]+)\p{Sc}/u", $post->post_title, $percentage, PREG_SET_ORDER);          
        if(isset($percentage[0][0]) && $percentage[0][0] != "" ){    
        $text = $percentage[0][1]." &euro;";

Comment: Do you mean you need to *extract* those substrings?

Comment: Yeah. I need to check if($text == "") then preg_replace_callback and if find the expressions in $post->post_title then $text is $m["num"] . " " . $m["cur"]

Comment: If yes means you need to get an array of those values, see https://ideone.com/zq4D5c.

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved me :)